# Trying to FOR LOOP a column with ST_CONTAINS in PgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am working with PgAdmin4 to create a View that consists of a large set of geometric data. Part of this data is polylines that exist within polygons. I am attempting to write a code that can loop through all of my polyline data in a given column, and check if it is in a given polygon, and return true/false. So far this is what I have.

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT "geom" FROM "street map"."segment_id")
    LOOP
        SELECT ST_CONTAINS(
            (SELECT "geom" FROM "street map"."cc_districts" WHERE "district number" = 1),
            (i)
        )
        RETURN NEXT i
    END LOOP;
END
$$
```

The error I receive when running this code is as follows:

```
ERROR:  loop variable of loop over rows must be a record or row variable or list of scalar variables
LINE 4:  FOR i IN (SELECT "geom" FROM "street map"."segment_id")
             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 18
```

From what I understand, "i" must refer to a "row variable", and I tried to define that variable with this piece of code:

```
(SELECT "geom" FROM "street map"."segment_id")
```

Any ideas to get this going would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to make this work without doing a `JOIN` or needing a `FOR LOOP`. The following code works.

```
SELECT * FROM "street map"."segment_id"
   WHERE
      ST_WITHIN(
          ST_CENTROID((ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326))), 
          ST_SetSRID((SELECT geom FROM "street map"."cc_districts" WHERE "district number" = 1),4326))
```

This lets me do what I was intending by runing the process on all rows in a given column. I swapped from `ST_CONTAINS` to `ST_WITHIN`, and I also am now checking if the centroid of the polyline is within the given polygon by using `ST_CENTROID`. I found that the error goes away by asserting the SRID of the geometry to 4326 using `ST_SetSRID`. I'm not sure why that works, as my geoms already have an SRID of 4326.

Thanks for all of those who answered

Comment: @JHG Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

A simple join would be much more efficient here

```sql
SELECT line.*, polygon.id IS NOT NULL AS is_in_polygon
FROM line
 LEFT JOIN polygon 
  ON ST_Contains(polygon.geometry, line.geometry)
     AND polygon.id = 1
```

Which can be translated as:

Get every field of a `line` record, and `true` if the `polygon.id` exists (`is not null`), `false` otherwise (more below). Name this boolean field `is_in_polygon`.
Do this on every line.
Join (link) each line to the polygon layer. If there is no match, keep the `line` information and put `NULL` for every `polygon` field (this is a `left join`). If there is a match, keep both `line` and `polygon` information.
A match is found if the `polygon.geometry` contains the `line.geometry` and if the `polygon.id = 1`

Comment: I'm not that well versed in this, but that doesn't seem to be working. It would be helpful if you could dumb this down a bit more for me. I appreciate the help!